# Opinion-based questions

Tags: discussion

About an hour ago I asked a [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61817/how-significant-is-3-additional-srgb-coverage-in-a-monitor-for-photographic-wor?noredirect=1#comment107447_61817). That was taken as a "primarily opinion-based" question in accordance to the first comment.

Initial title was "Is additional 3% of sRGB coverage and 3" worth additional 150$", so yes it is sort of primarily opinion-based. But essentially, everything in photography (IMHO) except pure technical aspects is opinion-based.

So, probably the words "opinion-based" are not correct in general? (By analogy with Stackoverflow I suppose that it is one of the reasons for question closing on this site).

Answer (score 2):

The opinion part is "is it worth it" question. That is up to you, but a better question is more about what gains are had by the differences as the edited title would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this (old but still relevant) blog post http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/.

In general, on Photo-SE, we're relatively tolerant of subjective questions about the art of photography itself (see ['Art' questions: how subjective is too subjective?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/950/art-questions-how-subjective-is-too-subjective)), and a lot less so on subjective questions about *gear* (which in many cases come down to personal preference rather than something where individual answers encompass a wide range of experience).

As Joanne notes, whether a feature or benefit is worth a certain dollar figure is *particularly* individual; it's better to ask about the importance and usefulness of the feature itself, and then judge the worth for yourself.

I think your basic question in this case is fine, and amenable to answer by experienced experts.